# MySql 'window function' and 'DATEDIFF, how to use?

Tags: mysql

I need to build query for mysql. If i use that query:

```
SELECT 
    Date, Time, EventId, UserId,
    Date - LEAD(Date) OVER W AS 'diff'
  FROM first
  WINDOW W AS (ORDER BY Date);
```

everything work. But i need to use `DATEDIFF()` function, like:

```
SELECT      
    Date, Time, EventId, UserId, 
    DATEDIFF(Date, LEAD(Date)) OVER W AS 'diff'
  FROM first
  WINDOW W AS (ORDER BY Date);
```

but i have an error now :

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') OVER W AS 'diff'   FROM first   WINDOW W AS (ORDER BY Date)'`. So how to use `DATEDIFF()` function?

The answer is :

```
SELECT 
    Date, Time, EventId, UserId, 
    DATEDIFF(DATE, LEAD(Date) OVER W) AS 'diff' 
  FROM first 
  WINDOW W AS (ORDER BY Date);
```

Comment: Answering your own question is fine, but you must post the answer part as an answer and accept it for that to be considered "Answered" as far as Stack Overflow is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is :

```
SELECT 
    Date, Time, EventId, UserId, 
    DATEDIFF(DATE, LEAD(Date) OVER W) AS 'diff' 
  FROM first 
  WINDOW W AS (ORDER BY Date);
```